# Finding links from the website using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jsoup

Im working on program which gets all the links from the webiste and searches for input word. Then enters each of this links and search again and etc. Program does this 3 times (thats why n is 3).
Code below does it with recursion method and seems to be working just fine.

However i would like to speed up this process by using threads. How can i implement this? From what i heard I can propably use fork/join for that.

```
 public static void getLinks(String url, Set<String> urls, String word, int n) {
    if(url.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + url);
    }

    if (urls.contains(url)) {
        return;
    }
    urls.add(url);

    if(n<3) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element element : elements) {
                System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
                getLinks(element.absUrl("href"), urls, word, n + 1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else return;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> links = new HashSet<>();
    String word = "root";
    getLinks("https://example.com", links, word, 0);
}
```

PS in the final version of the program links thats matching with input word will be printed in GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to submit `getLinks` to a `thread pool` while iterating through `Elements`:

```
    static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    static List<Callable<Object>> todo = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        getLinks();
        // Wait until all tasks are complete
        // Or use invokeAll(collection, timeout) if you want to have a maximum wait time
        executorService.invokeAll(todo);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static void getLinks(String url, Set<String> urls, String word, int n) {
        if(n<3) {
            try {
                for (Element element : new ArrayList<Element>()) {
                    todo.add(Executors.callable(() -> getLinks()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. One more question, where in the code should i put executorService.shutdown(). When I put it in the main right after calling getLinks function it immeditly stops executing the program.

Comment: You can't call shutdown immediately, you need to wait for all asynchronous tasks to complete. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a worker queue in which you submit runnables to be executed. As you discover links, you submit tasks for underlying pages to crawl.

Basically have a producer of work and consumer of work.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-blocking-queue